# split strings without removing splitter

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text,

```
text = "12345678 abcdefg 37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew 09089799 78998728 gdjewdwq"
```

And I want the output be:

```
12345678 abcdefg
37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew 
09089799 
78998728 gdjewdwq
```

I tried  "re.split("\d{8}", text)", but the result is incorrect.
How to get the correct output?

Answer (score 4):

You can use "Lookahead"

[Regex Tutorial - Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
import re
text = "12345678 abcdefg 37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew 09089799 78998728 gdjewdwq"
arr = re.split(r"\s+(?=\d)", text)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you looking to pair the numeric part with the alphanumeric and numeric will always be the first on each line

not an elegant of solution but addresses the question

```
splitted_txt = txt.split(' ')
i=0
while (i < (len(splitted_txt))):
    if (splitted_txt[i].isdigit() & ~(splitted_txt[i+1].isdigit())  ):
        print(splitted_txt[i], splitted_txt[i+1] )
        i+=1
    else:
        print(splitted_txt[i])
    i+=1
```

```
12345678 abcdefg
37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew
09089799
78998728 gdjewdwq
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @Itagaki's answer but it's worth noting that `findall` could also be used:

```
import re
text = "12345678 abcdefg 37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew 09089799 78998728 gdjewdwq"
```

```
re.findall(r"\d+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?", text)
  #=> ['12345678 abcdefg', '37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew', '09089799', '78998728 gdjewdwq']
```

[Demo](https://tio.run/##FY1LDoIwEED3nGLSFQQ12KLtmBgOIi6qLVCDBcYalMtX3L/P@A3d4EWM7jkOFIBsEuwnwBnYnovycJQK9O1ubNOCkAJLxTm0ZjG@m1xnlrezMxRYKJSIIBWiklytxMPOZp5YoonWGNld47zRfZ8Sq02eVqf6lV/0drnmWcU28J9myUjOh3RVshh/)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\d+       # match one or more digits
(?:       # begin a non-capture group
  \s+     # match one or more whitespaces
  [a-z]+  # match one or more lowercase letters
)         # end non-capture group
?         # make non-capture group optional
```

If it were required that there be exactly 8 digits and that the strings lowercase letters have lengths between (say) 7 and 15 (as in the example), the regex would be modified slightly:

```
r"\d{8}(?:\s+[a-z]{7,15})?"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match 8 digits, you can use:

```
\b\d{8}\b.*?(?=\s*(?:\b\d{8}\b|$))
```

**Explanation**

- `\b\d{8}\b` Match 8 digits surrounded by word boundaries to prevent partial matches
- `.*?` Match any char, as least as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
  - `(?:\b\d{8}\b|$)` Match either 8 digits or assert the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6F4CTg/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2x9uzw)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"\b\d{8}\b.*?(?=\s*(?:\b\d{8}\b|$))"
s = "12345678 abcdefg 37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew 09089799 78998728 gdjewdwq"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['12345678 abcdefg', '37394822 gdzdnhqihdzuiew', '09089799', '78998728 gdjewdwq']
```